# How to pre-select a day and month in form.date_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this date select form helper:

```
= form.date_select :universtity_start_date, start_year: Date.current.year - 3, end_year: Date.current.year - 15
```

I pre-select a year. But I also want to pre-select a day and month. How? There's no "start_date" in it.

Comment: Where do you pre-select a year? Your code doesn't show any pre-selecting.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select), it seems you can pass a `default` date to this method. `= form.date_select :universtity_start_date, ..., default: xxx`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
form.date_select :university_start_date, default: Date.today
```

or

```
form.date_select :university_start_date, default: 2.days.from_now
```